# Size of select box in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. Select boxes are always narrower than input boxes.

[image]

How can I make them the same width? Adding padding helps, but it looks ugly.

**EDIT**

Here is a little example  - http://jsfiddle.net/DfY8z/2/
Same example with custom class applied - http://jsfiddle.net/DfY8z/3/

I can use classes like `span3`, `span4` etc. But I want my inputs to fill all available space (and to be the same size) so I'm using custom class.

Comment: try class="span3" for both the boxes

Comment: It helps. But how can I set width manually in this case?

Comment: It results in different boxes size.

Comment: You'll need to change the width to the right one. Nilam just posted an example. Change 120px to whatever matches the size you want

Comment: Can you post the HTML you used to get the image above? I've seen this happen before when the markup isn't quite what the guys at Twitter were expecting you to use...

Comment: I've posted some simple piece of code

Answer (score 10):

Just adding `input-sm` class just next to the `form-control` worked for me.

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="xxx" ... >
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" value="" name=""><br>
<select>
 <option>Some options which is very very long... </option>
</select>
```

The result is the exact size of the boxes.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using an older version of bootstrap (current version is 2.2.1). Select boxes and input boxes in newer versions are the same size when no class is applied and when resized using the span* method

If you need to set a custom size you will have to use 2 different custom classes or target select boxes and input boxes individually. The input boxes need to be 14px smaller than select boxes (as do text areas).

See [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/DfY8z/5/)

```
// code sample because its required
<input class="myClass" type="text" value="Abcdefghijklmnop" />

<br />
<br />

<select class="myClass">
    <option> ABC </option>
    <option> XYZ </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

place the control

inside a  div and apply class="col-sm-2" on the div.

`<div class="col-sm-2">
<select></select>`

you can change col-sm-2 col-sm-3 as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me -
Go to bootstrap.css file and comment out the following --

```
select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
height: calc(2.25rem + 2px); }
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
<select style="width: 200px">...</select>
```

Comment: Inline styles are bad practice; instead, either the boxes need to be in consistent containers, or their style classes need to be coordinated.